# ASP.NET MVC w/ Newtonsoft passing objects from Controller to View

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I am trying to find the **cleanest way** to pass a object (recordset list) from the MVC 4 Controller to the View as a Json object.

**Controller:**

```
    var mem = BLL.Presenters.Account.GetAll().ToList();
    return View(mem);
```

**View:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load data from view 
    var globalData = @(Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)))
</script>
```

The javascript object has globalData which contains JSON.

Looking at the View, I am calling the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject, which I rather have in the Controller.

When I move the **JsonConvert.SerializeObject** to the Contoller:

```
   var mem = BLL.Presenters.Account.GetAll().ToList();
   var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mem);
   return View(json);
```

I get the error:  **Illegal characters in path.**

How can I pass along a json object (already Serialize) from the Controller to the View using Newtonsoft.Json ?

Comment: I'd say your first approach is actually fine and more flexible e.g. if you ever added more data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is misinterpretting your json (string) model as the name of a view and invoking the wrong overload of `View`. If you cast the model to object, you should be good to go:

```
return View((object)json)
```

Answer (score 1):

`return View(json);` is actually calling method `View(string viewName)`.

You need to put the json to the ViewData/ViewBag or ViewModel.